# Xamarin.Android notification with custom controls does not work in API26

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, android-notifications

I have a notification that shows a button to start a timer. This button works fine on API25, but with API26 and greater, the button does nothing.

I have already set up a notification channel. The notification itself shows up correctly, so I don't think it's a channel issue.

**Here I add the play/pause intent**

```
var playPauseIntent = new Intent("com.example.example.timer");
var timerNotificationIntentValue = this.GetTimerNotificationIntentValue(timerAction);
playPauseIntent.PutExtra("timerNotification", timerNotificationIntentValue);

const int playPauseIntentId = 0;
var playPausePendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this.context, playPauseIntentId, playPauseIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

contentView.SetOnClickPendingIntent(Resource.Id.btn_start_pause, playPausePendingIntent);
```

**And this is how I create the notification**

```
var channelId = "11e9a3a1-aebf-425d-a9e8-fcc2fb139664";
var channelName = "General";

NotificationChannel channel;

channel = notificationManager.GetNotificationChannel(channelName);

if (channel == null)
{
    channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationImportance.Max);
    channel.LockscreenVisibility = NotificationVisibility.Public;
    notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
}

channel?.Dispose();

Notification.DecoratedCustomViewStyle notificationStyle = new Notification.DecoratedCustomViewStyle();

notification = new Notification.Builder(this.context, "11e9a3a1-aebf-425d-a9e8-fcc2fb139664")
    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_logo)
    .SetStyle(notificationStyle)
    .SetCustomContentView(contentView)
    .Build();
```

**Then I just notify**

```
notification.Flags |= NotificationFlags.OngoingEvent;
notificationManager.Notify("1", notification);
```

When tapping on the button, nothing happens on API26.

**Something I notice**, is that on API25, when I tap the button, I get to the BroadcastReceiver, whereas on API26 I don't

Comment: it works for me on Android 8.0 with your codes,i don't know why do not work in your side,maybe you could try to add `playPauseIntent.SetClass(this,typeof(your broadcastreceiver));`,or you could share your project,i will test it

Comment: Sorry, I can't share the project code

Comment: does it work with setClass ?

Comment: No, it does not. I don't understand what the problem is... The code seems to be OK

Comment: yes,i test with your codes above,and it works

Comment: So you are able to touch a button in the notification and it goes to the OnReceived?

Comment: yes，it could work on my side

Comment: Thanks for trying. I'll keep looking. Maybe with NotificationCompat Builder

Comment: could it work now ?I've actually tried it with NotificationCompat Builder,both worked for me

Comment: Finally got it working. NotificationCompat didn't do anything. But I changed the `var playPauseIntent = new Intent("foo")` to `var playPauseIntent = new Intent(this.context, typeof(TimerNotificationBroadcastReceiver))` and it seems to be working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed this

```
var playPauseIntent = new Intent("com.example.example.timer");
```

to

```
var playPauseIntent = new Intent(this.context, typeof(MyNotificationBroadcastReceiver));
```

and now it seems to be working OK.